# Entity Framework 4 CTP 5 POCO - Using an existing but empty SQL database on hosting environment?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco, sql-server-ce

I'm using EF 4 CTP 5 with an MVC 3 application, everything is working fine on my local machine, where EF 4 just create or drop the SQL CE whenever it needs to, since I have set the option to `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. But I'm now trying to deploy my mvc application to a hosting environment, where I've created the database already, but the database is empty. It seems like the code can't drop, and recreate the database on my hosting environment, how should I solve this problem?

Update:

Here's the connection string to SQLEXPRESS:

```
<add name="KennySax"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
                       database=KennySax;
                       AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|KennySax.mdf;
                       User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Re-creating the database is a feature used during development, isn't it? Why would you want that in your deployed environment?

Comment: Then what should I be using? The database on my hosting environment is currently empty (no tables in it), I don't want to have to manually create the tables and relationship, isn't it what the "code-first" should do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure what I did, seems like a restart of the machine solved the problem. I was able to have SQLEXPRESS create the database and run the script on the hosting server. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One other option is to use Joachim Lykke Andersen's [DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged database initializer](http://devtalk.dk/2011/02/16/Workaround+EF+Code+First+On+AppHabour.aspx)

It deletes and re-creates the tables if the model changes

He even has a [NuGet package for it](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly)

Comment: Hi Richard, this is really nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually your running application in hosting environment doesn't have permissinons to modify DB structure. So you can run your application in your own environment and use Management studio to connect to SQL CE. Then generate SQL script from your DB and manually run that script in hosted environment. I hope it works with SQL CE - it will definitely work with SQL Express.

Comment: I've tried to change the SQL connection string to use my local machine SQLEXPRESS (which works alrite with other application), but somehow it doesn't generate any database at all. Here's the connection string (again, which work for a different application, I just named the database differently.):

Comment: Ran out of characters, so here is the connection string: ``<add name="KennySax" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserDB.csdl|res://*/Models.UserDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.UserDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\KennySax.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />``

Comment: This is connection string for EDMX model. You wrote that you are using code first, didn't you?

Comment: Delete your comment with connection string and update your question please. This is unreadable.

Comment: I've updated my original question with the connection string. Sorry, the previous one was copied wrong.